# card flip image is not constrained within view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have the following ViewController

```
import UIKit

class CardViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!

private let backImageView: UIImageView! = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "card_front_01"))
private let frontImageView: UIImageView! = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "card_back_01"))

private var showingBack = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    frontImageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
    backImageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill

    containerView.addSubview(frontImageView)
    frontImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false


    let singleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(flip))
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    containerView.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)
}

func flip() {
    let toView = showingBack ? frontImageView : backImageView
    let fromView = showingBack ? backImageView : frontImageView
    UIView.transition(from: fromView!, to: toView!, duration: 1, options: .transitionFlipFromRight, completion: nil)
    toView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    showingBack = !showingBack
}

}
```

Which basically consists of a view that get an image loaded within and when tapped card is flipped with another image.

My problem is that the images do not constrain to the view but appear to be placed at the top left of the viewController.

How can I get the cards to stay within the scope of the inner view?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, but you need to give either a Frame or constraints to your Image Views.

Since you are using `.scaleToFill`, the easiest method is to **not** disable the AutoresizingMask, and simply set the Frame to match the container view:

```
class CardViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!

    private let backImageView: UIImageView! = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "card_front_01"))
    private let frontImageView: UIImageView! = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "card_back_01"))

    private var showingBack = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        frontImageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        backImageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill

        containerView.addSubview(frontImageView)

        // don't disable Autoresizing
        // frontImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let singleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(flip))
        singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        containerView.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)

    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        // set the frames of the image views to match the containerView
        frontImageView.frame = containerView.bounds
        backImageView.frame = containerView.bounds

    }

    func flip() {
        let toView = showingBack ? frontImageView : backImageView
        let fromView = showingBack ? backImageView : frontImageView
        UIView.transition(from: fromView!, to: toView!, duration: 1, options: .transitionFlipFromRight, completion: nil)
        // don't disable Autoresizing
        // toView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        showingBack = !showingBack
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to generate constraints (NSLayoutConstraint) or set the frame of the subviews manually. Here is a generic example:

First set the image and add as subview:

```
imageView.image = image
containerView.addSubview(imageView)
```

Then:

OPTION 1: Set the frame of 'imageView' in it's superview coord' system

```
imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true // Must be true to use the frame        
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height)
```

OPTION 2: Set constrains for 'imageView' in it's superview

translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints prop of the view must be true in order to use constraints

```
imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
```